# how to code breadcrumbs (php kohana framework)?

Tags: php, kohana, hierarchical-data

is this good way to code breadcrumbs?

1. create table "categories" using mysql
2. create after neccessary columns "parent_id" column
3. if parent_id column have null value it means that this category is parent and if else this columns parent is a column with id which marked in "parent_id" column
4. recursively query to "parent_id" column starting at current column and print category name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breadcrumbs are easier if you use other methods of storing hierarchical data.

See my presentation [Models for Hierarchical Data with SQL and PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data) for examples of alternatives:

- Path Enumeration
- Nested Sets
- Closure Table

Answer (score 1):

You want to check out Modified Preorder Tree Traversal modules

- Sprig MPTT github.com/banks/sprig-mptt
- Jelly MPTT github.com/AlexKupreev/jelly-mptt
- v3 ORM MPTT github.com/kiall/kohana3-orm_mptt
- v2 ORM MPTT dev.kohanaframework.org/projects/mptt